# Excel VBA + Return multiple rows in TextBox based on values in ComboBox

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a VBA code in Excel to accomplish getting multiple rows into TextBox based on values selected in ComboBox. This is the following code that I have written. It is listing me only the last row but not all the rows that I would like to have. Ex. Column 76 is the where the ComboBox will show the values. If the values match then it should return me in the TextBox all values found in Column 77. i.e., If I select in my ComboBox BFSI, it should return me LIC of India & SBI. But my code returns only SBI.

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox22_Change()
    'Variable Declaration
    Dim iRow, StartLine, EndLine As Integer
    EndLine = 50
    iRow = 6

    'Clear Combobox2 before loading items
    TextBox21.Text = ""
    For StartLine = 1 To EndLine
        If ComboBox22.Text = Sheets("Pivots").Cells(iRow, 76) Then
                TextBox21.Text = Sheets("Pivots").Cells(iRow, 77)
        End If
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next StartLine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code will do that. The problem is that when it gets to the second "BFSI" cell, it will **overwrite** the first item from column 77 instead of appending it. Change this line

```
TextBox21.Text = Sheets("Pivots").Cells(iRow, 77)
```

to

```
TextBox21.Text = TextBox21.Text & "&" & Sheets("Pivots").Cells(iRow, 77)
```

The values from column 77 will then be **appended** to your TextBox value. In my example, they will be separated with a `&` symbol, adapt to match your needs.

Comment: Thank you nhee. TextBox21.Text = TextBox21.Text & vbCrLf & Sheets("Pivots").Cells(iRow, 77) was exactly what I needed.